# Como abrir uma imagem da WEB em um Timage no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, aplicação-web, imagem

Estou tentando abrir uma imagem que esta em um site meu, não posso usar o TWebBeowser pois ele tem um ScrollBar vertical que não dá para remover, então só me resta o Timage.

Comment: De uma olhada neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227646/how-to-get-images-from-url-in-delphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o componente IdHTTP para isso. Crie um novo projeto, jogue um componente IdHTTP e outro IdAntiFreeze no form, também um TImage e um TButton. Depois adicione o seguinte código no evento OnClick do Button:

```
var
  Jpeg: TJpegImage;
  Strm: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  Jpeg := TJpegImage.Create;
  Strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHttp.Get('http://www.site.com.br/imagem.jpg', Strm);
    if (Strm.Size > 0) then
    begin
      Strm.Position := 0;
      Jpeg.LoadFromStream(Strm);
      Image1.Picture.Assign(Jpeg);
    end;
  finally
    Strm.Free;
    Jpeg.Free;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
```

Se a imagem for muito pesada, recomendo que jogue esse procedimento dentro de uma thread.

Espero ter ajudado!